# error: cannot access 'arrayOfNulls': it is internal in 'kotlin.collections'

Tags: kotlin

What is wrong with this declaration if I want an array of List that contains Int?

```
private val set = arrayOfNulls<List<Int>?>(10) { 
    mutableListOf<Int>() 
}
```

Kotlin compiler says:

> Line 3: Char 23: error: cannot access 'arrayOfNulls': it is internal in 'kotlin.collections'
> private val set = arrayOfNulls<List?>(10) { mutableListOf() }

But `arrayOfNulls` exists if you declare it as:

```
private val set = arrayOfNulls<Node?>(5)
```

Comment: `arrayOfNulls<List<Int>?>(10) { mutableListOf<Int>() }` doesn't make sense. Do you mean `arrayOfNulls<List<Int>?>(10)`? What is `{ mutableListOf<Int>() }` doing there?

Answer (score 4):

The public function [`arrayOfNulls`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/array-of-nulls.html) takes only 1 parameter - the size of the array. You are giving it two parameters, `10` and `{ mutableListOf<Int>() }`. Because you passed two parameters, the compiler tries to find a function called `arrayOfNulls` that take two parameters, and it ends up finding [this internal function](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/7a7d392b3470b38d42f80c896b7270678d0f95c3/libraries/stdlib/common/src/kotlin/collections/CollectionsH.kt#L40):

```
internal expect fun <T> arrayOfNulls(reference: Array<T>, size: Int): Array<T>
```

Make up your mind about what you want:

```
// Array<List<Int>?> filled with nulls
arrayOfNulls<List<Int>?>(10)

// Array<MutableList<Int>?> filled with empty lists
Array(10) { mutableListOf<Int>() }

// Array<MutableList<Int?>> filled with empty lists. The lists can contain nulls
Array(10) { mutableListOf<Int?>() }

// Array<List<Int>?> filled with empty mutable lists,
// but there isn't much point in creating these mutable lists when you can't mutate them by accessing the array
Array<List<Int>?>(10) { mutableListOf() }
```